# Join other network using VPN so I can see other devices connected with the client on the same network

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a PC with a custom application on it to diagnose custom network over ethernet port it uses network adapter on windows and looks for IP 192.158.20.XX

this machine has it is own network with multiple hosts, so when my computer joins the network I can diagnose it

the main question is how to do it remotely I want my computer to join this network remotely so my device can see the other network as a network adapter

Because if I step OpenVPN connection between two sides I will be able to ping the device only not the other devices on the network, is possible to bridge the ethernet from Linux device to my computer so I can see the other network on my Windows as a network adapter so my app can see the network adapter and ping all devices on the network

Comment: You need to set OpenVPN up using a TAP interface.

Comment: @davidgo is possible to make TAP interface between 2 clients? as the server will be separated

Comment: I've.not used a TAP interface, but I would imagine this must be possible  - albeit inefficient. As I've not used these I can't comment on how this is set up.